# Django object of type 'method' has no len()

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I just added pagination to a ListView in Django, but it is returning `object of type 'method' has no len()` error, even though I am overriding the get_queryset method and it is not returning anything different from the queryset.

The view causing the error looks like this:

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = 'catalog/product/product_list.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def queryset(self):
        categories = Category.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.profile.company)
        return Product.objects.filter(category__in=categories)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['customers'] = Customer.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.profile.company)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.profile.company)
        return context
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipo/catalog/views.py", line 105, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipo/catalog/views.py", line 113, in get_context_data
    context = super(ProductList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 119, in get_context_data
    paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 69, in paginate_queryset
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 73, in page
    number = self.validate_number(number)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 51, in validate_number
    if number > self.num_pages:
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 100, in num_pages
    if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dawipoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 95, in count
    return len(self.object_list)

Exception Type: TypeError at /catalog/list/
Exception Value: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

How am I supposed to paginate with an overriden queryset without it showing this error?

Comment: Please show the *full traceback*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay, I placed the traceback right there.

Answer (score 0):

The method you override is [**`get_queryset(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset), not <s>`queryset`</s>, `queryset` is an attribute, you can set a `QuerySet` object for that, but not use `queryset` as a *method*. You thus implement this as:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProductList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'products'
    template_name = 'catalog/product/product_list.html'
    
    # use get_queryset, not queryset
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            category__company=self.request.user.profile.company
        )

    # …
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).